# Emailing when Scrapy project is finished

Tags: scrapy

So i re-read this  [page](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/email.html) in docs and still can't grasp in which files in project should i insert these lines?

```
from scrapy.mail import MailSender
mailer = MailSender()

mailer.send(to=["someone@example.com"], subject="Some subject", body="Some body", cc=["another@example.com"])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# ...
from scrapy.mail import MailSender
# ...
class MailSpider(Spider):
    # ...
    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        spider = cls()
        spider.mailer = MailSender()
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        return spider

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        spider.mailer.send(to=["someone@example.com"], subject="Some subject", body="Some body", cc=["another@example.com"])
    # ...
```

You could use signals like this to send the e-mail after the spider has closed. But I am not sure if this is the best way of doing this.

Also I believe you could send e-mails anywhere a python code is allowed.